# How to set solver settings for my non linear equations?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-system

I have a set of non-linear equations that I would like to solve using fsolve, shown below in WandG function. Solver solutions are far away from the ones I would expect, I am expecting something alike  x(1) = 10 and x(2)=0.11.

Therefore, I would be glad if someone could give me some better directions of how to set up the options, especially tolerances, of the solver.

So far, I am reading [this matlab documentation](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/when-the-solver-fails.html) and I was considering that I may have to rewrite my equations with a better scaling but I am not sure whether or not this will be sufficient.

Thanks in advance

```
% configuration of fsolve    
    options = optimoptions('fsolve','Display','iter-detailed','PlotFcn',@optimplotfirstorderopt);
    options.StepTolerance = 1e-14;
    %options.OptimalityTolerance = 1e-14
    options.FunctionTolerance = 1e-14;
    options.MaxIterations = 100000;
    options.MaxFunctionEvaluations = 400;
    options.Algorithm = 'levenberg-marquardt';%'levenberg-marquardt';%'trust-region'%
    fun= @WandG;

    x0 = [5.0000e+00;5.5366e-03];

    % Solve the function fun
    gw =fsolve(fun,x0,options);

    % Function to be solved by fsolve
    function F = WandG(x)

        F(:,1) = ((((x(:,2)./10).*0.1).*(x(:,1)./100)).^2).*(8.9856e+01) +(( 7e-11 .* ( x(:,1)./100 ) ).^2).*( 1.7040e+08.^2.*(8.9856e+01) ) - (((x(:,2)./10).*0.1).*(x(:,1)./100)); 
        F(:,2) = ((((x(:,2)./10).*0.1).*(x(:,1)./100)).^2).*( 8.0640e+00 - 1.7040e+08.*1.1e-7 * (1-x(:,1)./200) ) + (((x(:,1)./100).*7e-11).^2).*( 1.7040e+08.^2*(8.0640e+00 - 1.7040e+08*1.1e-7 .* (1-x(:,1)./200)) ) + 1.7040e+08.*(7e-11.*(x(:,1)./100) );

    end
```

Comment: I am almost certain that your problem doesn't come from one of the options, but as you say "with a better scaling". Everybody working in numerical analysis will say that you should never for example multiply a very very small number $(( 7e-11 .* ( x(:,1)./100 ) ).^2). \approx ?  1. e-22$ by a very very big one like $( 1.7040e+08.^2.*(8.9856e+01) ) \approx 3. e+18$

Comment: @JeanMarie thanks for replying, then should I down scale the whole function?

Comment: It's hard to say without having a mathematical description of this function. Could you provide one ? Often these very small ou very big numbers come from sticking to International System of Units.

Comment: @JeanMarie do you mean the full mathetamical equations system?

Comment: Not necessarily. Some hints about what the **initial** minimization problem looks like. Once again, is it a question of units like using Avogadro's constant ?

Comment: Yes, in principle the values `1.7040e+08`(is angular frequency), `7e-11`(capacitor value) and `1.1e-7`(inductor) are constants, since my equations comes from a circuit were some values are fixed.

Comment: For example instead of expressing $7e-11$ farad, use $0.7$ (taking  $10^6$ farad as the new unit).

Comment: Aside from fixing up scaling, etc., try setting x0 to what you expect the solution to be, i.e., [10,0.11] or whatever it comes out to after re-scaling.

Comment: @JeanMarie, but then shouldn't I scale all the equations with that factor or just the capacitor value?

Comment: @MarkL.Stone, that's exactly what I am doing too, I gave a value of `xo` in the code as an example. But to validate the soluton I use as intial point the expected solution

Comment: Don't think in terms of scaling because you will fall again into the same problem. A rule of thumb : take units such that coefficients in absolute value are all between $10^{-3}$ and $10^3$.